# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol 'R' on creating an activity inside a subpackage

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I'm trying to organize the files in my project, I searched for a way of organizing the files and I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102010/6866139, I created a project with no activities and added the packages and tried to create an activity inside the package name 'activities' then I got the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'R' [Here is the Project structure and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSpL1.jpg)

I did clean and rebuild but it does not work.
Is there any proper way to do this? Please let me know.

Comment: "R" is located in your build folder after you build the project. I'm not sure if its `edu.organisedapp.R` or `edu.organisedapp.activities.R`. Try any of it.
I would put MainActivity out of activities, because your identifier in Google Play would be edu.organisedapp.activities then.

Comment: It works, thank you so much!!!